# Ошибка при работе с Axios Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Здравтсвуйте, возникла проблема, при использовании Axios вместе с Vue.js. Когда отправляю GET запрос к серверу все рабоатет прекрасно:

```
... 
var self
axios.get("/adminRoom/changeTask", {
    params: {
        title : self.changingForm.oldTitle,
        newTitle : self.changingForm.newTitle,
        newTitle : self.changingForm.newDescription,
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    ... 
});
...
```

Но стоит поменять GET на PUT,DELETE или POST как на клиенте так и на серверу так сразе же перестает все работать. ВВот ошибка:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status http//:loclahost:8080/adminRoom/changeTask:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () of 400 ()

Error: Request failed with status code 400
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at XMLHttpRequest.l.(anonymous function) (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:3278)
```

Спустя какое-то время удалось наладить работу с POST запросами таким методом:

```
...
var self = this;
const requestParams = new URLSearchParams();
requestParams.append('title', self.addingForm.title);
requestParams.append('description', self.addingForm.description);
axios.post('/adminRoom/tasks/addTask', requestParams).then(function (response) {
    ...                  
});
...
```

Но PUT и DELETE также остаются не работоспособными. Может подскажет кто-нибудь, в чем проблема...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вдумчиво прочтите [список кодов HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP)
Axios с Vue тут совершенно ни при чем. Вам же 400 бэкенд кидает. Убедитесь, что бэкенд на этом роуте обрабатывает запросы, отличные от GET.

Comment: Только странно то, что когда кидаю POST запрос с теми же параметрами к серверу через Postman, то все работает прекрасно, а через axios... Сервре не причем.

Comment: Ну в вашем примере и нет параметра name

Comment: @Владимир, если работает через Postman, значит с сервером всё в порядке и вы передаёте парметры не так как надо